# Converting audio files with sox while keeping date/time information

Tags: audio, sox

I am converting .ima files, collected by an audiologger, into .wav format. It works fine, but when doing this I loose the information about the date/time at which the (original, .ima) files were created. Is there a way of having the .wav files somehow 'timestamped' so I could recover the date/time at which the audio was recorded?

Many thanks for any hint provided.

Comment: You could include the date/time in the name?  If you want a full-featured solution there is also a format called [Broadcast WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_Wave_Format) which is based on the WAV format but allows for metadata in the file.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I will have a look at the Broadcast format. And I may end up scripting something to get the date/time in the filename (I have hundreds of files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you can either:

### Store the date/time information in the file name

For example, store files with file names in the format `2018-09-23-19-53-45.wav`, or whatever time format you like.

### Store the audio in Broadcast WAV format files (BWF)

[Broadcast WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_Wave_Format) is based on WAV format but allows for metadata in the file.  The difference between a Broadcast WAV file and a normal WAV is the presence of the BEXT chunk, and as such the file is compatible with existing WAV players.

The BEXT chunk contains two appropriate fields called OriginationDate and OriginationTime.  The layout for the chunk can be found here:  [BEXT Audio Metadata Information](http://bwfmetaedit.sourceforge.net/bext.html).